# C++ how to apply a function to vector elements

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, vector, transform

I would like to write a C++ function to apply a (lambda) function on a vector and return another vector of the same size:

```
template <class T, class UnaryOperator>
T transform_vector(const T& input, UnaryOperator op)
{
    T output;
    std::transform(input.begin(), input.end(), std::back_inserter(output), op);
    return output;
}
```

This code works, if the function `op` return type is the same as `T`. Is there is way to tell the compiler that the type of the output vector is the same as the return function of the `op` to make this code work in general case?

Comment: Could you add some code where it works, and some code where it doesn't work, to better illustrate what problem you need solved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> there is way to tell the compiler that the type of the output vector is the same as the return function of the op to make this code work in general case?

**-- EDIT --** `std::decay<>` systematically added following a Barry's comment (thanks!)

I suppose something like (if you can use C++14)

```
template <class T, class UnaryOperator>
auto transform_vector(const T& input, UnaryOperator op)
{
    std::vector<std::decay_t<decltype(op(*input.begin()))>> output;
    std::transform(input.begin(), input.end(), 
                   std::back_inserter(output), op);
    return output;
}
```

For C++11 is a little more complicated (and redundant) because you can't simply use `auto` as return type

```
template <class T, class UnaryOperator>
auto transform_vector(const T& input, UnaryOperator op)
   -> std::vector<typename std::decay<decltype(op(*input.begin()))>::type>
{
    std::vector<typename std::decay<decltype(op(*input.begin()))>::type>
       output;
    std::transform(input.begin(), input.end(), 
                   std::back_inserter(output), op);
    return output;
}
```

Another way, that works starting from C++11 and avoid redundancy, pass through a third template type parameter with default value.

It's a little more complicated but I (IMHO) is more interesting because permit to avoid the automatic deduction through `decltype()` and impose a different return type.

```
template <typename T, typename UO,
   typename RetV = std::vector<typename std::decay<decltype(std::declval<UO>()
                                        (*std::declval<T>().begin()))>::type>>
RetV transform_vector (T const & input, UO op)
{
    RetV output;
    std::transform(input.begin(), input.end(), 
                   std::back_inserter(output), op);
    return output;
}
```

This works also with C++11.

Starting from C++14 you can symplify using `std::decay_t<T>` instead of `typename std::decay<T>::type`.

Comment: Your solution works in general (just tested with C++14). Thanks

Comment: @motam79 - answer improved with another way (a little more complicated but (IMHO) preferable), without redundancy, that should work starting from C++11.

Comment: Awesome, I didn't know it is possible define another "derived type" within the template < ... >.  It also works if an empty vector is passed to the function.

Comment: You'll want to add `std::decay_t` to the result of invoking `op`

Comment: @Barry - You're right, obviously. But there is no way my brain become used to `std::decay`. Thanks.

Comment: @motam79 - answer corrected following a Barry's comment.